# Erro a abrir Partial's numa nova aba a partir de uma função no javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte caso: Tenho uma página de navegação de "Terceiros", com várias `Partials` que definem os seus dados correspondentes.

Para fazer essa navegação estou a fazer por `javascript`, e carrego as `Partial` da seguinte forma (exemplo de uma partial):

```
$("#divContactosTerceiro").empty();
$("#divContactosTerceiro").load("Terceiros/sContactosTerceiro", { NumRegistoTerceiro: result.result.NumRegisto });
```

Aqui envio os dados `NumRegistoTerceiro` para o `controller` `Terceiros/sContactosTerceiro`. Até aqui tudo bem, funciona perfeitamente.

**O que estou a fazer agora?**
Estou a abrir numa nova aba a partir de uma página de `Alertas`, a página dos `Terceiros`, onde vai executar a função `javascript` do exemplo do código acima.

**Problema?**
É que o `javascript` acrescenta duas vezes o nome do controller a carregar a `Partial` na nova aba, como mostra a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é que posso contornar este problema? Não encontro nenhuma referência útil na net.

Comment: Não funciona se você usar `.load("~/Terceiros/sContactosTerceiro"`?

Comment: Não funciona se usar `.load("Terceiros/sContactosTerceiro"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Coloque assim:**

```
$("#divContactosTerceiro").load("/Terceiros/sContactosTerceiro")
```

**Problema:**
A barra antes de Terceiros está faltando por isso a duplicação

Comment: Obrigado, estive 2h de volta disto por causa de uma `/` :P

Comment: é o MVC muda alguns conceitos e a `/` faz a diferença, que bom ajudar